# How to print all npm peer dependencies of a module from a private git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, package.json

Within the package.json file I can successfully refer to the module as follows:

```
"[module name]": "git+ssh://git@[host of private repo]:[repo name]/[module name].git"
```

However the following attempts to get the peer dependencies fail:

```
npm info "git+ssh://git@[host of private repo]:[repo name]/[module name].git" peerDependencies

npm info "https://[host of private repo]/[repo name]/[module name].git" peerDependencies
```

In both cases, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Invalid package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     [PATH]/.npm/_logs/2018-03-06T18_22_24_434Z-debug.log
```

But it works when I attempt this for a public module:

```
npm info eslint-config-airbnb peerDependencies
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Query with the module name instead of its uri:

```
npm info module_name peerDependencies
```

Comment: I get an error saying that: module_name is not in the npm registry. I believe my registry only points to the public npm module repository. I would need to have access to both the public and private repository when installing my packages.